# Does Breezejs support IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, breeze, indexeddb

I am looking for a JS library I can use for data access with my HTML5 app. I plan to use the IndexedDB for my local data and had looked at Breeze but it doesn't appear that Breeze has any support for IndexedDB.

Since Breeze has quite a bit of data functionality I thought I was wrong so I looked in the Breeze.debug.js file and didn't see any references to IndexedDB.

I have Breeze 1.4.2

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the docs on the Breeze.js website.

> #### Offline support
>
> The EntityManager is able to serialize its state to a
>   local persistence store and later rematerialize that state.
>
> `exportEntities` -    Serializes any selected group of
>   entities to a string for storage to HTML5 local storage or IndexedDb
>   or any other local persistence store.
>
> `importEntities` -    Deserializes any previously 'exported' entities into the entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze JS does not support indexedDB at this time because it exports everything as a string in a proprietary format which is difficult to store properly in indexedDB.

I have a pull request waiting which adds support to BreezeJS to support this functionality. Feel free to use it and +1 it if you would like the breeze JS team to bring this pull request into the main codebase.

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/pull/22